# Download Images from a server to display on the CollectionView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, afnetworking

I am working on a product application where user could sell/buy. This application is based on collection view. Collection view has collection cell where it displays product image thumbnail.

The following code gets products images from the server and it waits to download all images and then display them in the cells. The following code works but user is waiting 10-20 seconds to see all products. Is there a better way to handle ?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
     [super viewDidLoad];
     dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0ul);
     dispatch_async(queue, ^(void) {
        [self loadFromURL];
     dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
     });
  });
}

-(void)loadFromURL {
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://myURL/productAll.php"];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
    operation.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];

   [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) 
     {        
      pElements= (NSMutableArray *)responseObject;
      [collectionView reloadData];

     } 
     failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) 
     {        
       UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error Retrieving Product" message:[error localizedDescription]delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
     [alertView show];
   }];    
  [operation start];
}

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return pElements.count;
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    ProductCell *cell=[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellIdentifier" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
    NSString *arrayResult = [[pElements objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"image"];
    NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithBase64EncodedString:arrayResult options:NSDataBase64DecodingIgnoreUnknownCharacters];
    cell.productImage.image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
    cell.productImage.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
    cell.productImage.clipsToBounds = YES;
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: If you are looking for a code review you should ask at http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Actually, I have modified my question, I am trying to find out how to reduce the time that user waits to see the products on the collection view.

Comment: @rmaddy: This does not look like a code review but asking for different opinions on how to optimize a "non-perfect" code.

Comment: @erolyeniaras The question was changed after I posted that comment.

Comment: @ texas Nice quistain

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a response from the server in which the image data for all of the images is base-64 encoded in the response. This means that the response is likely very large and won't be shown to the user until everything is downloaded.

Instead, you might consider refactoring your server code to not include the image data in base-64 format, but rather to just include a URL (or some identifier) that can be used to retrieve the image later. Your response should be much smaller and should be able to be processed much more quickly.

Then, when `cellForItemAtIndexPath` is called, rather than extracting the image data out of the original response, you lazily (and asynchronously) request the image for the cell. AFNetworking provides a nice `UIImageView` category in `UIImageView+AFNetworking` that asynchronously retrieves images from network source. (And using this category gets you out of the weeds of lots of subtle issues when doing asynchronous image retrieval.)

By the way, if your images are of varying sizes, you might want to include the dimensions of the image in the original request so that the cells and their image views can be appropriately sized up front, rather than resizing them as the images are retrieved.

--

A couple of observations:

1. You don't need to dispatch `[self loadFromURL]` to a background queue, as that's already asynchronous. And I'd probably use `GET` of the request
2. You can't just cast `responseObject` to `NSMutableArray`, because it probably is not mutable. You really should use `NSArray` or use `mutableCopy` if you *really* need it to be mutable.
3. You're doing some cell configuration in `cellForItemAtIndexPath`. Most of that (clipping, background color, etc.) can be done right in IB, so I would do it there rather than doing it programmatically. The only thing you might need to do programmatically is the rounding of the corners (and, even that, I'd probably do with a `IBDesignable` subclass, though that's beyond the scope of this question).

Thus, assuming (a) your array has a new property called `imageURL` which is the URL of the image; and (b) the cell has a fixed sized image view, you could do something like:

```
@interface ViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *pElements;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];

    [self loadFromURL];
}

-(void)loadFromURL {
    NSString *urlString = @"http://myURL/productAll.php";

    [self.manager GET:urlString parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation * _Nonnull operation, id  _Nonnull responseObject) {
        self.pElements = responseObject;
        [self.collectionView reloadData];
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation * _Nullable operation, NSError * _Nonnull error) {
        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error Retrieving Product" message:[error localizedDescription]delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alertView show];
    }];
}

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return self.pElements.count;
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    ProductCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellIdentifier" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSString *imageURL = self.pElements[indexPath.row][@"imageURL"];

    [cell.productImage setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageURL]];
    cell.productImage.layer.cornerRadius = 10;

    return cell;
}

@end
```

Comment: Thanks  a lot Rob, for writing  a really nice informative answer. I wonder If you could able to illustrate a little bit of `UIIMageView+AFNetworking`?

Comment: My other concern is now I am getting all products first and then display them on the collection view. Is there a better way to handle that? For example, if any single image is downloaded from the server, then display it immediately. In other words, do not wait all the images to be downloaded.

Comment: @texas If you remove the base-64 coded data from the original response, and then use `UIImageView(AFNetworking)` category (e.g. `setImageWithURL:`) inside `cellForItemAtIndexPath`, then it will get all the products first (which should be reasonably quick) and then display the images as they come in, i.e. it will _not_ wait for all the images to download. If you google "AFNetworking UIImageView setImageWithURL tutorial" or things like that, you should get good hits, such as http://www.raywenderlich.com/59255/afnetworking-2-0-tutorial

Comment: Thanks a lot Rob, appreciate all your help and efforts. I have accepted and upvoted your answer. I hope many other SOF users will get benefit out of it

Comment: @Rob: Can you apply the same logic if you keep the images as BLOB s in the database instead of image URL?

Comment: Sure, but you need to just have implement some URL on your web service that you can pass some identifier for the blob and it will return the resulting image.  For example, you might have a unique identifier for that row in the table, and you would implement a new PHP that takes that identified and returns the image. I would even make that PHP not base-64 encode the image in JSON, but return the actual image.